# SQL Server - Split Non-Normalized Column With Delimiter Into Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to split `specialty`, that is non-normalized column into multiple columns using a comma delimiter:

Input:

```
ID    specialty
236y  GINECOLOGIA E OBSTETRÍCIA - RQE 184
356z  ALERGIA E IMUNOLOGIA - RQE Nº 26, DERMATOLOGIA - RQE Nº 122, MEDICINA DO TRABALHO - RQE Nº 25
678k  CIRURGIA GERAL - RQE Nº 442, CIRURGIA VASCULAR - RQE Nº 443
```

Desired output:

```
ID    specialty_1                      specialty_2      specialty_3
236y  GINECOLOGIA E OBSTETRÍCIA - RQE    NULL                  NULL
356z  ALERGIA E IMUNOLOGIA - RQE      DERMATOLOGIA - RQE   MEDICINA DO TRABALHO - RQE
678k  CIRURGIA GERAL - RQE         CIRURGIA VASCULAR - RQE                     NULL
```

I can split column using `substring` and `charindex` in a scenario where there are the same number of delimiters, but in cases like this, where there is no pattern, I don't know exactly what to do

Any ideas?

Comment: Will you always have a constant number of output columns? For example, do you know you'll ***never*** need more than three specialities? If you know you need a varying number, put each speciality in a separate row, not a separate column; *[STRING_SPLIT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)* . In fact, as you sometimes have less than three specialities, it's already normal to recommend multiple rows rather than sparsely populated columns.

Comment: Your desired output is violating 1NF with what is known as repeating groups. And even more fun is your source data is impossible to split accurately with the lack of delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

I have this function `fn_SplitStrings_Moden` that will split a delimited string into a table (each row has one of the delimited string). I use it in some way in all my databases. This example probably has bad performance over a large database but accomplishes what you asked. The only issue is that you have to know the maximum number of specialties and create the corresponding number of columns. To do a fully dynamic solution would take a stored procedure or dynamic SQL.

The other commenters are correct in that storing delimited lists in a column is not what SQL is good at. Instead, all the specialties should be listed in a separate table and then have an association table that stored the person's ID and the associated specialty... with that said, here's how to accomplish what you asked.

```
--Function takes a delimited string and a delimiter char, 
--returns a table where each row is a separate string from the delimited list.
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_SplitStrings_Moden]
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
FROM cteStart s;

--Create a table var for test data.
DECLARE @testData TABLE (
    ID nvarchar(500)
    , specialty nvarchar(4000)
);

--Load some test data.
INSERT INTO @testData (ID, specialty)
VALUES
    ('236y','GINECOLOGIA E OBSTETRÍCIA - RQE 184')
    , ('356z','ALERGIA E IMUNOLOGIA - RQE Nº 26, DERMATOLOGIA - RQE Nº 122, MEDICINA DO TRABALHO - RQE Nº 25')

--Final Query
SELECT
    td.*

    --To get first specialty, do a top one from the split strings function.
    , (SELECT TOP 1 item FROM dbo.fn_SplitStrings_Moden(td.specialty,',') ORDER BY Item ASC) as specialty_1
    
    --To get the next specialty, use a row number.
    , (SELECT TOP 1 item FROM (
        SELECT item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY item) as row_num FROM dbo.fn_SplitStrings_Moden(td.specialty,',') 
        ) as t(item,row_num)
        WHERE t.row_num = 2
      ) as specialty_2

    --Rinse and repeat to get each subsequent specialty. 
    --Increment the WHERE t.row_num = X for each new column.
    , (SELECT TOP 1 item FROM (
        SELECT item, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY item) as row_num FROM dbo.fn_SplitStrings_Moden(td.specialty,',') 
        ) as t(item,row_num)
        WHERE t.row_num = 3
      ) as specialty_3
FROM @testData as td
;
```

Example Results:

[image]